# Cassandra::AccessError: Invalid column family "users"

Tags: ruby, cassandra

client = Cassandra.new('keyspacetest', '127.0.0.1:9160')

2.1.0 :019 > client.insert('users', '0', {  'id' => 'John', 'email' => 'jsmith@test.com' })
Cassandra::AccessError: Invalid column family "users"
    from home/cassandra/columns.rb:59:in `column_family_property'
    from home/cassandra/columns.rb:44:in`column_name_class_for_key'
    from home/cassandra/columns.rb:12:in `column_name_class'
    from home/cassandra/helpers.rb:21:in`extract_and_validate_params'
    from home/cassandra/cassandra.rb:399:in `insert'
    from (irb):19
    from home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in`'

**database:**

cqlsh:keyspacetest> select * from users ;

id | email
 hi | 123@gmail.com
cqlsh:keyspacetest> DESC TABLE users ;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id text,
  email text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id))
)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're trying to insert data into CQL table/column family using "pure" Thrift API. 
That doesn't work well. If you want to use CQL then you have to use a client library which will allow you to execute CQL statements (https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb for ex.).

Comment: 2.1.0 :001 > require 'cql'
 => true 
2.1.0 :002 > client = Cql::Client.connect(hosts: '127.0.0.1:9160')
NameError: uninitialized constant Cql

client CQL::Client.connect
NameError: uninitialized constant CQL::Client
 from (irb):3